# Python - why it doesn't create a new instance of object?

Tags: python, class, object, instance

I have a little problem that I do not understand.

I have a method:

```
def appendMethod(self, newInstance = someObject()):
    self.someList.append(newInstace)
```

I call this method without attributes:

```
object.appendMethod()
```

And actually I append the list with the same instance of someObject.

But if I change it to:

```
def appendMethod(self):
    newInstace = someObject()
    self.someList.append(newInstance)
```

I get new instance of that object every time, what's the difference?

Here's an example:

```
class someClass():
    myVal = 0

class otherClass1():

    someList = []

    def appendList(self):
        new = someClass()
        self.someList.append(new)

class otherClass2():

    someList = []

    def appendList(self, new = someClass()):
        self.someList.append(new)

newObject = otherClass1()
newObject.appendList()
newObject.appendList()
print newObject.someList[0] is newObject.someList[1]
>>>False

anotherObject = otherClass2()
anotherObject.appendList()
anotherObject.appendList()
print anotherObject.someList[0] is anotherObject.someList[1]
>>>True
```

Comment: this question isn't *strictly* related to the mutable default value, but is about *when* default values are created. @tomek keep in mind that every function keeps a **`tuple`** of its default values in the `__defaults__` attribute. But, what does this mean? Well, surely since `tuple`s are immutable functions *cannot* create a default value every time they are called, hence the default value is created only *once* at function *definition*. 
Try to change `someObject` with a function like `def func(): print("called")` and see when this function gets called.

Comment: This is a good question. It certainly confused me when I came from C++-land where functions are second-class objects evaluated at function execution rather than function definition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you are assigning your default argument as a mutable object.

In python, a function is an object that gets evaluated when it is defined, So when you type `def appendList(self, new = someClass())` you are defining `new` as a member object of the function, and it does NOT get re-evaluated at execution time.

see [“Least Astonishment” in Python: The Mutable Default Argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-in-python-the-mutable-default-argument)

Comment: thank you, now I understand what happens. It's counter intuitive to me, but I get it. I forgot to think of functions as objects.